# Optimize touchesBegan UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

Next, I learned that to close the virtual keyboard when clicked anywhere on the screen, we must implement the touchesBegan method together with the name of the variables, which bind with the existing view UITextFields.

If we have about 10 text fields, I learned that I have to repeat this command 10 times:

```
[MyFristTextField resignFristResponder]; 
[MySecondTextField resignFristResponder]; 
... 
[MyTenTextField resignFristResponder];
```

Is not there any easier way to do this, for example, call UITextFields all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the current UITextField in a property.  Then send `resignFirstResponder` to that UITextField when you want the keyboard to dismiss.

Comment: Give me a exemple, please

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to implement 10 times.

What you can do is just use:

```
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
```

At the method that you are calling from the tap Gesturrecgnizer.

For example:

```
    self.tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(closeAllKeyBourds)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tap];
```

Your code should look something like:

```
  -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
    self.tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self          action:@selector(closeAllKeyBourds)];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tap];
  }

  {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
 [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tap];
 self.tap = nil;
  }
```

Tip:

If you are using 10 TextField, you better place then on a scroll view, so you can lift the scroll view up when using a lower text Field.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**

You have to keep an instance variable, or a property of the TapGestureRecognizer, so you can refer to it when the tap occurred. 
So you keep a property at your @inerface, it should look like so:

```
  //At your interface:
  @interface LogInpageViewController : UIViewController
  //Keep a property 
  @property (nonatomic,strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;
```

Comment: Edited my answer for you.

Comment: Sorry! to close all TextFields call: [self.view endEditing:YES];